# problem with ubuntu 12.10 as it is not showing up in boot menu

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot

i installed ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows 7. I alloted 25 GB for it. It installed well but when i restarted again I dont get to select Windows 7 or Ubuntu. It directly boots to Windows. When i put the Ubuntu Cd, it tells that Windows 7 and ubuntu are both installed and if u want to reinstall Ubuntu. I tried that but again I dont get to select Windows or Ubuntu. Please help.. New to Ubuntu

Comment: As a starter try to do a boot repair. Link here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair it fixes most issues

Comment: Do you mean that you are unable to see the boot menu that lets you select either Ubuntu or Windows 7, or do you mean that you _do_ see the boot menu, but it is not letting you boot to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

just reinstall the bootloader, GRUB2, but you must do it via live cd ubuntu.. or you can read guideline from this http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7